# Datatables sort rows that have a certain class name first

Tags: datatables

So basically when a row is clicked, I add a class to that parent TR. Then I redraw the table.

```
$('#datatables').on( 'click', 'tbody tr:not(".group")', function (e) {
        if($(this).hasClass('transfer')) {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }

        table
                .order( [ 7, 'asc' ] )
                .draw();    
        if($('tr.selected').length > 0) {
            $('#ts_btn').removeClass('hidden'); 
        } else {
            $('#ts_btn').addClass('hidden');    
        }
    } );
```

But how can I get the table to put the selected rows at top?

I tried this:

```
"columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [7],
                "visible": false,
                render: function ( data, type, row ) {                  
                  if (type == 'sort') {
                      return $(row).hasClass('selected') ? 1 : 0;
                  }  else {
                      return data;
                  }    
                }  
            }
        ],
```

But it doesnt work.

The reason I'm not using the new Row Select for Datatables is because I use a barcode scanner to read and I filter based on what it is to select the row. (in addition to clicking the row)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of achieving this:

1. Create a hidden column.

```js
var columnDefs = [
    //... Some other columns...
    {
        title: "selected",
        visible: false,
        searchable: false
    }
];
```

2. Fill it with zeroes.

```js
var dataSet = [
    [
        // some data,
        0
    ]
    // ...
]
```

3. Enable a [fixed descending order](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed) on that column.

```js
myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    orderFixed: [
        0, // index of the hidden column
        'desc'
    ],
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
    select: 'multiple'
});
```

4. On select events, browse selected rows, and set the value of the cell for the hidden column to 1.

```js
myTable.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function (e, dt, type, indexes) {
    if (type === 'row') {
        var $rows = myTable.rows(indexes);
        var data = e.type === 'select' ? 1 : 0;
        $rows.every(function(index){
            myTable.cell(index, 6).data(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vctls/es8h2zo9/

I specifically needed a way of keeping selected rows first regardless of user-defined sorting, but you can change the selector and the event handlers to suit your needs.
There might be a way of making it work with static data, if you don't want to add all the zeroes, but I couldn't find one.
Also, this obviously won't work out of the box with serverside pagination.